# How to take line from a list box and then, turn thw string into an int

Tags: c#, winforms

I was working on a program the calculates your GPA where you put your grades(in numbers) and in a list box, but i can figure out how to take every line in the list box and turn it into it's own string an then convert it to an int.

I didn't try anything' because i couldn't think of a solution.

Comment: "I didn't try anything' because i couldn't think of a solution." You surely have at least some hello-world, don't you? How should we know to what degree you need help? Do you know what a class is? What a namespace is? What a variable is? Please give us more information on where *specifically* you need help.

Comment: Firstly, the `ListBox` has an `Items` collection so how can it be hard to get one or more items? Secondly, where did the data come from in the first place and, if you want `int` values out, why aren't you putting `int` values in in the first place? You need to deal with one problem at a time and explain what that problem actually is. If you just don't know how  a `ListBox` works then you should spend some time to learn. If you do know how a `ListBox` works then you wouldn't be asking us how to get an item or items from it, so that's not an actual problem.

Comment: Just start from product documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Answer (score 0):

To loop through all values selected in the list box:

```
foreach (var i in listBox1.SelectedItems) {
    int intval = Convert.ToInt32(i.ToString());
    // utilise intval here
}
```

If single item selection is allowed (SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One) just use:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) {
    int intval = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.SelectedItems[0].ToString());
    // utilise intval here
}
```

They assume the list box is filled by "grades(in numbers)".